# How to animate to a translucent colour in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation, colors

Simplified(!) example:

```
<Window Background="Black">

    <Button Background="#ff272727"
            Content="Whatever"
            Foreground="White"
            Padding="16,8"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="container" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:2" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="container"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                                    To="#33ff8000" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>

</Window>
```

When hovering over the button, I would expect the colour to transition from `#ff272727` (opaque dark gray) to `#33ff8000` (translucent orange) over a duration of 2 seconds. However, what actually happens is that it first transitions very quickly (I estimate about a quarter of a second) to what looks like `#ffff8000` and only then continues to `#33ff8000` over the rest of the 2 seconds.
Essentially, it seems like it is animating the colour and alpha components one after the other rather than both at the same time.

Interestingly, the same thing does not happen if I exchange the alpha values of the two colours, i.e. when I animate from a translucent colour to a fully opaque one. It only seems to happen when the `To` colour is not opaque.

Another interesting observation for me was that the exact same phenomenon occurs even with this storyboard:

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="container"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"
                     To="0.2" />
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="container"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                    To="#ffff8000" />
</Storyboard>
```

This will also first animate the colour and then the opacity...

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known issue? If so, are there any known workarounds?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue with WPF .NET Framework 4.8, specially when making it 20 seconds it shows that both the alpha and the color transitioning is at same time.

Comment: I can reproduce it with Framework 4.8. However, I have by now found that the problem appears to be at least partially dependent on the specific colour values. I have indeed found a few colour combinations where I also wasn't able to reproduce it. I have a suspicion that the fact that one of the involved colours is fully desaturated (i.e. it is a gray) might be a factor, but I haven't had time to verify this yet. Have you tried it with the exact colour values from my example?

Comment: Yes I did, and I did try with Black/White. In both cases same result

Comment: First thought is that I would have a translucent background with a colored "panel" (rectangle, etc) in front / on top. I would vary the opacity of the panel until the background was revealed; then delete the (now redundant) front panel. UWP has a "translucent" brush; as well as WPF via the Community Toolkit. Varying the opacity of the translucent, varies what shows through that. Very nice where I have (moveable) "toolboxes" where I want the background "canvas" to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a case of your eyes playing tricks on you. Light is a tricky thing and it's intensity is not linear (either logarithmic or closer to square kind of depending on what aspect of light intensity/color we're talking about). Furthermore, going from gray to orange-ish is a much shorter step than the reduction opacity, so your eyes perceive this happening much sooner than the opacity change.

Here are a couple links that go deeper into that topic:

- https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/1587
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw

To illustrate this phenomena with your example, I changed your template to show what the animation is doing. In the result below, you can see that it is indeed moving through both values linearly.

```xml
<Button Background="#FF272700" Foreground="White" Padding="16,8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="container" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="16,8">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Background.Color, ElementName=container}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Background.Opacity, ElementName=container}" />
                </Grid>
                <!--<ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />-->

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:05" />
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard Changed="Storyboard_Changed">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="container" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity" To="0.2" />
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="container" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#ff8000" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

[image]

The fix is going to be to change the speeds and/or start points of your animations separately to get them to appear the way you want.

Comment: Wow, that is wild... Using your trick, I can now confirm that both color and opacity are indeed animating at the same time. I would not have expected the opacity animation to behave this way, though... My expectation was that what I tried here would be exactly equivalent to doing a straight color animation from the original colour to the colour that is the result of layering the translucent target colour on top of the background colour. This does not appear to be the case...

Comment: OK, I'm not sure if I would really call it a "trick of the eye" but I can accept the explanation of what is happening, especially because it disproves my original analysis of the problem. Still quite disappointing that animating with opacity is not the same as animating directly between the blended colours (the same unfortunately applies to gradients as I now discovered ). Would be great if there was a way to inject an alternative interpolation mode that would behave in a less surprising way...

Comment: FYI: I have created a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78232823/9784